# IE 8 and below incorrectly sizing iframe contents on browser zoom

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iframe, zooming

There is an embedded Vimeo video on a site I'm developing. Nearly all of the target audience uses IE8 or below, and for reasons unknown nearly all of them have their browsers zoomed to 125% view. Thankfully everything else on the site works under those conditions, but the video in the iframe is zooming oddly and cutting off content.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj87J.jpg

That is an album with the iframe normally and zoomed, as well as the embed code provided by Vimeo. There is absolutely nothing special in my CSS or JS that changes the iframe's default properties. I'm *certain* I'm not the first one to have this problem, but apparently I just don't know how to ask the question to lord Google. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 8 will automatically zoom to 125% by default if your display settings are set to 120 DPI. This does however sometimes confuse plugins such as Silverlight and Flash. It is possible to detect the zoom level in script and you could potentially use this to make adjustments. See [Making the Web Bigger: DPI Scaling and Internet Explorer 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc849094.aspx).